# Add another `pipe` in rxjs angular generate error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have strange behavior in Angular.

This code works:

```js
this.form.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(this.form.value),
                pairwise(),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),,
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            )
            .subscribe(([oldValue, newValue]) => {
                this.updateOrder['id_order'] = newValue.id_order;
            });
```

but when I add another `tap`

```js
this.form.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(this.form.value),
                pairwise(),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                tap(() => console.log('aa')),
                takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            )
            .subscribe(([oldValue, newValue]) => { // console shows that problem is here
                this.updateOrder['id_order'] = newValue.id_order;
            });
```

I've got this error

> error TS2548: Type '{}' is not an array type or does not have
> a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

Remove body from all of methods doesn't change anything.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Something is returning an object and something else is expecting an array (probably the result passed to `subscribe` since you're using array destructuring there).

Comment: I edit post to be more clear.
Seventh `tap` always arise a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pipe` accepts a finite number of operators, just split them in two `pipe`s:

```
.pipe(
  ...
).pipe(
  ...
).subscribe( ... )
```

Comment: Wow. it was exacly the problem.

Here is the source of pipe:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f920974f2fa12650f249d2a0f52630e95e6dd1e8/src/internal/Observable.ts#L404

Answer (score 0):

`tap(() => this.checkDeliveryAddress())` -> After this you are getting an object, not an Array. Thats why.

Comment: Not sure since the first block of code is working. So no problem with `checkDeliveryAddress` method. But the next one, `this.checkInvoiceAddress()` is probably the issue.

Comment: Could you please check if you are returning an object in the invoice function ?
@burasuk

Comment: I'm not the author.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.